# Can't seem to deploy pygame app with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Trying to bundle an app with `pyinstaller` using:

```
pyinstaller —onefile —debug all —icon=<icon_file> —name=name my_enter_point.py
```

but getting the following err:

```
import 'pygame
settings not found in PYZ
code object from 
import 'settings' 
shooter not found in PYZ
code object from 
import 'shooter' 
game_functions not found in PYZ
code object from
bullet not found in PYZ
```

(I tried using `--paths=.` but I got `pygame._freetype not found in PYZ`)

settings shooter bullet is my own module files and in the same dir as my_enter_point.py

so my project looks like (all files and images folder in the same level):

```
images_folder

Main file:
import sys
import os
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from a import A
from b import B
import c as C
from d import D
from e import E
from f import F

file b:
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

file g:
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

file h:
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

file c:
import sys
import pygame
from g import G
from h import H
from time import sleep

file e:
import pygame.ftfont
from pygame.sprite import Group
from b import B

file f:
import pygame.font
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file `my_enter_point.py` to `main.py` and try again.

EDIT:
Also, first try to use only these parameters `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py`

Comment: didin't helped getting the same err (".. not found in PYZ")

Comment: sorry to hear that. What is your python/pygame version? Have you tried with simple example just to see if everything works in that case?

Comment: python 3.7.4
pygame 1.9.6
Yes, simple example works.

can you tell what 'not found in PYZ' means?

Comment: `.pyz` is an extension which contains files with python code which can be executed by interpreter. I think `PYZ` is class that makes some kind of spec file which is used for importing. I'm not 100% sure, so please correct me if I made any mistakes and provide additional info if needed. Do you have second level imports (e.g. main.py imports A module and then in A you have import B)? If so, correct this. Also put all required files in the same directory. Let us know any of this worked

Comment: Thanks.
I have added the project dependencies in main thread.

only images folder is not in the same level, but i'll put that folder with the exe file.

Comment: No problem, I hope you'll manage to solve the issue. Another thing that springs to my mind. Put all files you need in `dist` folder (should be created automatically), then start your `.exe`. If this does not work also, I'm afraid I do not have any more ideas..

Comment: tried it didn't work. I don't think i need all the files in dist only the images folder which i'm accessing in my code.